# Deleting User account using Passwordless Authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I have implemented passwordless SignUp/SignIn from firebase for my react-native app but I can't understand how will the delete account method work if it needs to be reauthenticated with a password or needs a recent SignIn to refresh the token??

In short, how should I use `reauthenticateWithCredential()` when I'm using Passwordless Authentication??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase documentation on [Linking/re-authentication with email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#linkingre-authentication_with_email_link) has an example of how to get a credentials object from the email link/passwordless sign in:

> ```
> var credential = 
>     firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink(email, window.location.href);
> ```

You can then pass this `credential` to your call to `reauthenticateWithCredential`.

Comment: I'm using firebase for my react-native app, and the second parameter of ```credentialWithLink()``` is a https web link, so where should I get this link from ??
Do I send an email to the user with that link ??

Comment: Assuming that you're using `react-native-firebase` (please indicate so in your question, or better yet: tag the question with it), they also have that method here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/packages/auth/lib/providers/EmailAuthProvider.js#L46

Comment: Yes sorry for that, I am using ```react-native-firebase```. But I'm not sure how do I get the emailLink as its not a web page and there is no https link.
Kindly help me :)

Comment: I haven't used email link sign in myself yet. But the documentation says that the email contains a Firebase Dynamic Link, and then you can use that to open the app (since React Native apps run on Android and iOS, they're still native apps), and you can then create the credentials based on that link.