# Firebase anon user to be linked to an email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Would anyone know how we could implement the following with Firebase auth. Docs/searches haven't produced a good answer yet. So the use case is as follows:

1. User comes to a site to buy something. We allow them to buy without any sign-up barrier and on checkout, just ask them for their email. An anonymous user is created and their purchase is sent to their email provided.
2. With that email, we'd like to set up a passwordless account for them so that the user can log in later just with their email and see items bought in their dashboard. For that the anon uid recorded with the purchase needs to be associated with the email.

So the question is how to achieve that an anon account upgraded to a registered account with the email provided.

We've tried inserting a passwordless sign-in link sending at the point of the purchase, but it just created a new account with a new id, which is not what's needed. We need the uid to stay the same as the anon user's so that we can simply connect their purchases to the newly email-authenticated account. Perhaps, there is a way of associating an anon uid with an email before sending that passwordless signin link?

Hope this makes sense, but please do ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: You are supposed to upgrade the anonymous account to a regular account by linking them in your code: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account

Comment: Yes, Doug, I saw that article. As you saw, it doesn't give any example for the passwordless use case. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

To create a `Credential` object from an email link, you can use the [`EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider#static-credential-with-link). You can then use this credentials object to upgrade your anonymous account.

Also see: [Deleting User account with using Passwordless Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510590/deleting-user-account-with-using-passwordless-authentication/59512911#59512911)

Comment: Thanks, Frank, but that's not quite what needs to be achieved. Basically, if a user buys something, that's when their anon uid is registered. We just need to associate that purchase with their email so that they can see the purchases later on. The question how to do that. Link may not be clicked on until later and that browser might be closed by then. Association needs to happed at the point of sale. Is it feasible?

Comment: "We need the uid to stay the same as the anon user's so that we can simply connect their purchases to the newly email-authenticated account." This means you need to link the signed-in anonymous account with the email-link credentials. The method I mention is the way to create the necessary credentials object to allow that.

Comment: Ok, it would make a link, but only after a user clicks on the email? What if they don’t do until they closed the browser or a few days later. That anon UID that they used during the checkout will be gone by then, won’t it? The link might be made, but not with the right UID, correct?

Comment: Anonymous UIDs persist across application restarts, and survive until you explicitly log the user out, or uninstall the app.

Comment: This is for mobile, what about a web user opening a new browser the following day?

Comment: Same thing. The UID is persisted there too.

Comment: That's not quite what happens in practice:
1) User comes to the site for the first time, anon UID is created, they enter email as part of signup, which is added to their details in the db
2) An email is sent to them to verify the email
3) However, user misses it for whatever reason.
4) Instead, they come again with a different device and try to log in using a password-less login by entering their email and receiving a link
5) they get the link and click on it. The email gets verified, but gets assigned to a NEW UID created on the 2nd visit.
How can it be linked to the 1st UID instead?

Comment: Sorry, there is still a bit that's unclear is how to let a user who was given an UID to convert that UID into an email/password combo. Perhaps, doing it on the backend with admin rights?

Comment: There's no "conversion" per se, but you'd create credentials with the `EmailAuthProvider` and then link them to the existing anonymous account as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, though they don't quite provide a solution to the problem. Is there an option to thank for the inputs though it's not a solution to the question?

Comment: I think I've found a workaround by creating a passwordless sign-in link which associates the anon account with their email. That way even if next time when they use another device and log in using passwordless sign-in, it'll retrieve their original UID rather than create a new one as the email is associated with the old anon address.